# How to exclude gitlab CI job from pipeline based on a value in a project file?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, rules

I need to exclude a job from pipeline in case my project version is pre-release.

*How I know it's a pre-release?*

1. I set the following in the version info file, that all project files and tools use:

```
  version = "1.2.3-pre"
```

2. From CI script, I parse the file, extract the version value, and know whether it's a pre-release or not, and can set the result in an environment variable.

The only way I know to exclude a job from pipeline is to use `rules`, while, I know also from [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) that:

> rules are evaluated before any jobs run

`before_script` also is claimed to be called with the script, i.e. after applying the rules.

I can stop the job, *only after it starts from the script itself*, based on the version value, but what I need is to extract the job from the pipeline in the first place, so it's not displayed in the pipeline history. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you run (start) your pipeline, and is the information whether "it's a pre-release" already known at this point?

If yes, then you could add a flag like `IS_PRERELEASE` as a variable to the pipeline, and use that in the `rules:` section of your job. The drawback is that this will not work with automatic pipelines (triggered by a commit or MR); but you can use this approach with manually triggered pipelines (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#override-a-variable-when-running-a-pipeline-manually) or via the API (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#pass-cicd-variables-in-the-api-call).

Comment: Right, it can be always done manually, but I was hoping to find an automatic solution, thanks

Comment: Well, it certainly can be automated, but you probably need two pipelines: one determining the scope of work, and with this information, triggering the second one which will actually perform.

Comment: Thanks Hannes. The main objective actually is "not displayed in the pipeline history", this solution still runs and displays a pipeline/job (the one determining the scope) in the project jobs history.

Comment: Your question states you want to skip one /job/ from a pipeline. Your comment suggest you want to "hide" the whole pipeline? Would you be able to modify the push command to include the required information?